# Jest expect to array contains element

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Let's suppose that I have the following code:

```js
const id = '1'

const arrayOfIds = ['1', '2', '3']
```

And I want to check if `id` is **in** `arrayOfIds`

Something like this

```js
expect(id).toBeIn(arrayOfIds)
```

How can I do this with `Jest`?

Comment: Would `expect(arrayOfIds.includes(id)).toBe(true)` work?

Comment: No, must be the contrary

Comment: So, `toBe(false)`? But you asked _"check if `id` is in `arrayOfIds`"_?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`.toContain`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tocontainitem) when you want to check that an item is in an array. For testing the items in the array, this uses ===, a strict equality check.

```
test('is id in arrayOfIds', () => {
        const id = '1';
        const arrayOfIds = ['1', '2', '3'];
        expect(arrayOfIds).toContain(id);
});
```

Comment: btw If you need to check one object in an array, `.toContainEqual()` is better. 'It checks the equality of all fields, rather than checking for object identity.'

Answer (score 0):

```
    expect(['a', 2, '3']).toContain(2);
    expect(['a', 2, '3']).toContain('3');
```